# Storing and retrieving data in the cloud and retrieving via webservices

Tags: web-services, cloud

I am writing some home automation application wextended with an mobile application. The home devices would store their statuses online and should be able to check if there is some kind of command (turn light on, start washing maschine,...) for them to execute.

Are there any service providers that would let me store and retrieve information online, possibly without me having to write the webservices and authentication part for the server side?

If yes then are there service providers that would do this for free if I am a noneprofit enduser just trying to automate his own home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many such services which are coming up now which give you a cloud data-store without writing code on cloud.

Listing some:

1. http://parse.com/ (A facebook company now). They have a good free usage plan to start with, and is very easy to use (I have tried personally)
2. https://www.firebase.com/
3. AWS DynamoDB. If you are familiar with AWS, this is a good option.
4. [Dropbox Datastore](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore)

All of them give client side SDK - for Android, iOS etc.