# NoSQL, jquery, scalable database cloud service for HTML/CSS/JS phonegap web app

Tags: database, cloud, hosting

I am developing a web app (HTML/CSS/JS) destined to be used as is and also compiled with phonegap for iOS/Android/and others. I am loging my users using OpenId Connect.
I am looking for a database hosting service. It should be NoSQL, readable/writable by jquery and scalable.
I need to store the user's contact info and other user choices from my app.
I am thinking about using Cloudant with a CouchDb database, but I am really new to this.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Amazon Web Services, take a look at [Dynamo DB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/). It is infinitely scalable. You can start for almost free and pay more as and when your data-size and request load increases. It can guarantee you the same low response time even with huge data. 
You can use this [from JS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html) as well

I have discussed some other options in this other SO thread - Parse, Firebase, Dropbox DataStore etc. Have a look: [Storing and retrieving data in the cloud and retrieving via webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262174/storing-and-retrieving-data-in-the-cloud-and-retrieving-via-webservices/22264536#22264536):

Comment: I havent personally used these. From what I know, if you use CouchDB, you will have to manage the DB maintenance, uptime, scaling on your own. You can instead look for CouchBase (a Managed CouchDB): http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/why-couchbase

Comment: One huge benefit of DynamoDB is again that it is "fully managed". You say how much load you anticipate and pay for it. They do the rest ! If you are in the CouchDB route, CouchBase could get to closer to this.